# How to get table all current row information

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am new to swift . i am doing my project programatically and I load data from api to the tableView and tableView like ios setting page  ..
[image]

now i need all rows information when click "Add to cart" button. How can i do it?

here is my code sample :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cartHeaderCell, for: indexPath) as! CartHeaderCell

        cell.configureCell(indexPath.item)

        return cell

    case 1:

        let obj = data?[indexPath.row]

        var cell = UITableViewCell()


        switch obj {
        case  is Addon:

            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: addonCell, for: indexPath) as! AddonCell

            let switchView = UISwitch(frame: .zero)

            switchView.setOn(false, animated: true)



            cell.accessoryView = switchView


            guard let addon = obj as? Addon else {

                return cell

            }

            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(addon.name) + €\(addon.price)"

        case  is AddonGroup:

            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: addonGroupCell, for: indexPath) as! AddonGroupCell
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.disclosureIndicator

            guard let addonGroup = obj as? AddonGroup else {

                return cell

            }

            if let addons = addonGroup.addonList {

                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""
                var selectedAddons = ""
                for _addon in addons
                {
                    if _addon.isSelect == true {

                        selectedAddons = selectedAddons + "\(_addon.name)"


                    }  

                }

                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = selectedAddons
            }

            cell.textLabel?.text = addonGroup.name
         ...........................................
```

Comment: I assume you just want to get the user selections by getting all the rows of the table? `UITableView` only creates the rows that are visible - so you cannot get all the rows from the table view. Instead, this should be handled via your data model used to populate the table view. If you want to persist the user selections as the user makes them, you should detect the specific events and update your model. If you need more info, I'd be happy to help.

Comment: @Fahim thanks .. how can i do it could you tell me please or provided answer i will accept and upvote

Comment: It would depend on how you have the data for the table view set up. From where does the `configureCell` method get data for configuring each cell view? That would probably be your starting point. Then, when the user makes a choice from the table view, you have to add the data for the choice to that model. I can give a more detailed answer if I can see the project code. Are you able to share the project with me?

Answer (score 0):

As Fahim was mentioning, you need to set up a data model that records that status of each cell before / during / after the user interaction with each cell. So when the cell goes off screen and then comes back on, it will be presented with the correct state of the model.

Secondly, for the UISwitchViews, you should be instantiating and adding those to the contentView within each cell in order to keep the cellForRow function clean and problem free. The reason leads me into my next point: how to record the status of each UISwitchView after the user has interacted with a UISwitchView. You are going to want to create a protocol and add a delegate within the UICollectionViewCell(that inherits class and the delegate should be a weak var), in order to update the model whenever the UISwitch is tapped.

If you have any more questions i can do my best to help!